# Selecting the Step-length in Coordinate Descent?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

Consider the picture attached [the algorithm of coordinate descent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65lRe.png) of the Coordinate Descent Algorithm taken from *Wright, Stephen J.*, [**Coordinate descent algorithms**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10107-015-0892-3), Math. Program. 151, No. 1 (B), 3-34 (2015). [ZBL1317.49038](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1317.49038).

Its explanation says ".... Turning to step-length αlpha-k, we may perform exact minimization along the ik component, or choose a value of αlpha-k that satisfies traditional line-search conditions (such as sufficient decrease), or make a predefined “short-step” choice of αlpha-k based on prior knowledge of the properties of f."
I want to ask the following:
1. the explanation which says that we may perform exact minimization along the ik component, what does it mean?
2. Can I have some examples or relevant material which shows this concept through an example.
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

1. It means that you can pick $\alpha$ in the expression under the step 'choose index' such that $f(x^{k+1})$ is minimized.
2. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_descent).

Comment: I do not understand what is exact minimization vs the popular Line search

Comment: @OmerAjmal What do you consider 'popular line search'?

Comment: like the golden ratio and brent's minimization algorithms

Comment: Those are exact minimization algorithms (for convex functions). These are in contrast to inexact line seach, such as [backtracking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backtracking_line_search).

Comment: right, that is great

Comment: but I would like some more opinions and elaboration on that, although your answer has cleared a very important concept